# jaxrs could not find my custom (de)serializers for joda.money type

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I have written my custom (de)serializer for `joda.money.Money`type. I register them with Object Mapper. But when I deploy my war file, it says could not find serializers for joda.money.Money type.

```
import org.joda.money.Money;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

    public class MoneyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Money> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MoneyDeserializer() {
        super(Money.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Money deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Registering in the ObjectMapper;

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider;
import org.joda.money.Money;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;
import xx.serializers.MoneyDeserializer;
import xx.serializers.MoneySerializer
@Provider
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    public JsonProvider() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        // Register <Money> (de)serializers
        SimpleModule tstmodule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
        tstmodule.addDeserializer(Money.class, new MoneyDeserializer());
        tstmodule.addSerializer(Money.class, new MoneySerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(tstmodule);

        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());

    }

}





  2:24:00,860 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 151) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./api: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./api: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("sale") on public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.xx.getItems(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,org.joda.money.Money,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String) for basetype: org.joda.money.Money
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at 

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("sale") on public javax.ws.rs.core.Response xx.getItems(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,org.joda.money.Money,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String) for basetype: org.joda.money.Money
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.StringParameterInjector.initialize(StringParameterInjector.java:218)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you create `ObjectMapper` in `JsonProvider` constructor but never use it. You probably should use `setMapper(mapper);` on JsonProvider at the very end of the constructor.

But i don't think this will solve your problem. I think the problem is that jaxrs understands only simple data types and if you want to use custom class you have to implement some sort of String marshalling for String based `@*Param`

From your stacktrace i see that you use `jboss`, so maybe this can help? https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html/StringConverter.html

> What if you have a class where valueOf() or this string constructor
>   doesn't exist or is inappropriate for an HTTP request? JAX-RS 2.0 has
>   the javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider to help in this situation.
>   See javadoc for more details.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverterProvider.html

Something like this should probably work:

```
@Provider
public class MoneyConverterProvider  implements ParamConverterProvider {

    private final MoneyConverter converter = new MoneyConverter();

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (!rawType.equals(Money.class)) return null;
        return (ParamConverter<T>) converter; 
    }

    public class MoneyConverter implements ParamConverter<Money> {

        public Money fromString(String value) {
            if (value == null ||value.isEmpty()) return null; // change this for production
            return Money.of(CurrencyUnit.EUR, Double.parseDouble(value));
        }

        public String toString(Money value) {
            if (value == null) return "";
            return value.getAmount().toString(); // change this for production
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..But StringConverter is deprecated..Now what is the replacement?

Comment: Im using RestEasy 3.0.12.Final version with wildfly 9.0

Comment: @Ratha i updated my post. I think you should use  `javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider `