# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime] from String

Tags: rest, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly, fasterxml

I have Java8 LocalDateTime in my Jax-RS REST APIs. My webapp is deployed in wildfly10. When i make a POST call(which includes LocalDateTime as parameter) i get following exception;

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime] from String value ('2016-06-02T00:08:25.605Z'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@396d1714; line: 2, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.leightonobrien.core.model.base.Company["created"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:843)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:284)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1150)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
```

Based on following guides  ;

[Wildfly throws "Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.QueryParam" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449340/wildfly-throws-unable-to-find-a-constructor-that-takes-a-string-param-or-a-valu/37449703#37449703)

and

[jaxrs could not find my custom (de)serializers for joda.money type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041353/jaxrs-could-not-find-my-custom-deserializers-for-joda-money-type/37045744?noredirect=1#comment61674458_37045744)

and

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310

I have written my provider and registered in the application path;

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

@Provider
public class LocalDateTimeConverterProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    private final LocalDateTimeConverter converter = new LocalDateTimeConverter();

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (!rawType.equals(LocalDateTime.class))
            return null;
        return (ParamConverter<T>) converter;
    }

    public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements ParamConverter<LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime fromString(String value) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
            return dateTime;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(LocalDateTime value) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            String formattedDateTime = value.format(formatter);
            return formattedDateTime;
        }

    }

    public LocalDateTimeConverterProvider() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        setMapper(mapper);
    }

}



import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
@Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(com.test.JsonMoneyProvider.class);
        set.add(com.test.DurtaionConverterProvider.class);
        set.add(com.test.LocalDateTimeConverterProvider.class);
        set.add(com.test.MoneyConverterProvider.class);
...
```

I make POST call like;

```
 curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "created": "2016-06-02T00:08:25.605Z",
  "updated": "2016-06-02T00:08:25.605Z",
  "id": 0,
  "code": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "abn": "string",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "address1": "string",
      "address2": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "country": "string",
      "gps": {
        "latitude": {
          "latitude": 0,
          "value": 0
        },
        "longitude": {
          "longitude": 0,
          "value": 0
}' 'http://localhost:8080/test2dbwar/rest/Companys'
```

How can I overcome above issue? Now I'm clueless..I tried to put all stuff (try to avoid wildfly's jax-rs complex support issue, jackson serialization issue) and sort out the issue..

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question you linked to involves conversion of `@XxxParam` annotations. This is what the `ParamConverterProvider` is for. This is a completely different (de)serailization process from *entity body* (de)serialization.

For entity (de)serialization, `MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter`s are used. Jackson provides one such implementation, in its `JacksonJsonProvider/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`, which you are currently using, whether you know it or not. So the configuration for the `LocalDataTime` needs to somehow be configured with that provider.

The only way to configure Jackson support for the `LocalDateTime` serialization, is through it's `ObjectMapper`. You can create a custom `Json(De)Serializer`, as mentioned [in this post (Option two)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738293/2587435), or you can use the `JSR310Module` (that already has custom `Json(De)Serializer` for `LocalDateTime`), mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803634/2587435).

To actually configure the `JacksonJsonProvider/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` to use your configured `ObjectMapper`, you can use a `ContextResolver`, as mentioned in both of the previous links, or you can construct the `JacksonJsonProvider` with the `ObjectMapper`, and register that provider

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper..configurModuleOrSerializer
JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
registerProvier(provider)
```

Personally I would just go with the `ContextResolver`, as mentioned in the links. The difference is that with the above code, the `ObjectMapper` is provided to the provider explicitly, while with the `ContextResolver`, during runtime, the provider will search the JAX-RS registry for a `ContextResolver` of type `ObjectMapper`, and then obtain it that way.

Comment: Sorry, Im really new to Hibernate. Thanks for the clear explanation. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding the following works for me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.9</version
</dependency>
```

and configure the `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```